# How to get total amount of dynamic input form in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have dynamic 2 input

```
<div class="row" v-for="(line, index) in form" :key="index">

   <input
     type="number"
     placeholder="Number"
     class="form-control"
     :ref="`number_${index}`"
     v-model="line.number"
     @keyup.enter="goNext(index)"
   />

   <input
    type="number"
    v-model="line.amount"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Amount"
    :ref="`amount_${index}`"
    @keyup.enter="addLine(index)"
   />
</div>
```

How to calculate total of only amount input

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're binding incorrectly <del>`v-model="line.number"`</del> the inputs to your array items, the correct is  `v-model="lines[index].number"`:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(line, index) in form" :key="index">

   <input
     type="number"
     placeholder="Number"
     class="form-control"
     :ref="`number_${index}`"
     v-model="form[index].number"
     @keyup.enter="goNext(index)"
   />

   <input
    type="number"
    v-model="form[index].amount"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Amount"
    :ref="`amount_${index}`"
    @keyup.enter="addLine(index)"
   />
</div>
```

The total should be a computed property by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method like :

```
computed:{
  total(){
   return this.form.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
       return acc+Number(curr.amount);

   },0);
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      form: [{
        number: 0,
        amount: 0
      }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addLine(index) {
      this.form.push({
        number: 0,
        amount: 0
      })
    },
    goNext(index) {


    }

  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      return this.form.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + Number(curr.amount);

      }, 0);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>Total : {{total}}</div>
  <div class="row" v-for="(line, index) in form" :key="index">

    <input type="number" placeholder="Number" class="form-control" :ref="`number_${index}`" v-model="form[index].number" @keyup.enter="goNext(index)" />

    <input type="number" v-model="form[index].amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" :ref="`amount_${index}`" @keyup.enter="addLine(index)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer when i use `lines[index].number` its show 0 undefine `line.number` works fine but calculation not correct its show `1+1=11` not 2 when i change `v-model.number` its undefine now

Comment: i also tested that acc is getting undefine after add more form

Comment: I made a mistake here `lines[index]` it should be `form[index]`, inside the computed property add `return acc + Number(curr.amount);` in order to cast the string to a number, i edited my answer with working code